Send coins/jettons on TON blockchain using Python
How can I send coins/Jettons (for example, Notcoin) from one TON blockchain wallet to another using Python?
No one SDK has a working example. 

The ton community provides the asset-sdk along with its usage examples.
The code below is an example of transferring the jettons:
import {Address, toNano} from "@ton/core";
import {AssetsSDK, createApi, createSender, importKey, PinataStorageParams} from "../src";

async function main() {
    const NETWORK = 'testnet';
    const api = await createApi(NETWORK);

    const keyPair = await importKey(process.env.MNEMONIC!);
    const sender = await createSender('highload-v2', keyPair, api);

    const storage: PinataStorageParams = {
        pinataApiKey: process.env.PINATA_API_KEY!,
        pinataSecretKey: process.env.PINATA_SECRET!,
    }

    const sdk = AssetsSDK.create({
        api: api,
        storage: storage,
        sender: sender,
    });

    console.log('Using wallet', sdk.sender?.address);

    const JETTON_ADDRESS = Address.parse('MY_JETTON_ADDRESS');
    const jetton = await sdk.openJetton(JETTON_ADDRESS);

    const RECEIVER_ADDRESS = Address.parse('RECEIVER_ADDRESS');
    const myJettonWallet = await jetton.getWallet(sdk.sender!.address!);
    await myJettonWallet.send(sender, RECEIVER_ADDRESS, toNano(10));
}

main().catch(console.error);


From main docs
from pytoniq import LiteBalancer, WalletV4R2, begin_cell
import asyncio

mnemonics = ["your", "mnemonics", "here"]

async def main():
    provider = LiteBalancer.from_mainnet_config(1)
    await provider.start_up()

    wallet = await WalletV4R2.from_mnemonic(provider=provider, mnemonics=mnemonics)
    USER_ADDRESS = wallet.address
    JETTON_MASTER_ADDRESS = "EQBlqsm144Dq6SjbPI4jjZvA1hqTIP3CvHovbIfW_t-SCALE"
    DESTINATION_ADDRESS = "EQAsl59qOy9C2XL5452lGbHU9bI3l4lhRaopeNZ82NRK8nlA"

    USER_JETTON_WALLET = (await provider.run_get_method(address=JETTON_MASTER_ADDRESS,
                                                        method="get_wallet_address",
                                                        stack=[begin_cell().store_address(USER_ADDRESS).end_cell().begin_parse()]))[0].load_address()
    forward_payload = (begin_cell()
                      .store_uint(0, 32) # TextComment op-code
                      .store_snake_string("Comment")
                      .end_cell())
    transfer_cell = (begin_cell()
                    .store_uint(0xf8a7ea5, 32)          # Jetton Transfer op-code
                    .store_uint(0, 64)                  # query_id
                    .store_coins(1 * 10**9)             # Jetton amount to transfer in nanojetton
                    .store_address(DESTINATION_ADDRESS) # Destination address
                    .store_address(USER_ADDRESS)        # Response address
                    .store_bit(0)                       # Custom payload is None
                    .store_coins(1)                     # Ton forward amount in nanoton
                    .store_bit(1)                       # Store forward_payload as a reference
                    .store_ref(forward_payload)         # Forward payload
                    .end_cell())

    await wallet.transfer(destination=USER_JETTON_WALLET, amount=int(0.05*1e9), body=transfer_cell)
    await provider.close_all()

asyncio.run(main())


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
